# My Script Task Doesn't run the latest code

Tags: ssis

I have a simple VB Script task that sends Email. If I change a email subject or a code chunk and run the package the change doesn't take into effect. I tried putting a breakpoint, during runtime the new code chunk is not even there. And, If I stop the code and just go to the code editor, the update is still there. Finally the updated code does takes effect when I run/build solution for about 10-20 times or so. After some play-around, I found out that the problem is only with script changes. It is very wierd. So, far I have tried restaring my machine, Visual Studio 2008 and rebuilding the project but nothing really helps. Now I am thinking cache, project configuration... I am lost.
Here is my Script File.

```
    Dim myHtmlMessage As MailMessage
    Dim mySmtpClient As SmtpClient
    Dim myBody As String = ""
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim mySubject As String = "LOL"
    myHtmlMessage = New MailMessage(Dts.Variables("EMailFrom").Value.ToString(), Dts.Variables("EMailRecipients").Value.ToString(), mySubject, myBody)

    mySmtpClient = New SmtpClient(Dts.Variables("SMTPServer").Value.ToString())
    mySmtpClient = New SmtpClient("lol")
    mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = True
    mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = False
    mySmtpClient.Send(myHtmlMessage)
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
```

The problem isn't really in the script but the way the script behaves. So if I change the mySubject value it doesn't takes affect .

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the script task completely; the entire object, not just the code inside. Save, recompile, run - make everything works. Now add a new task, and start adding your code gradually.